# Can't use Docker CLI through SSH on Windows 10

Tags: docker, ssh, windows-10

I turned on SSH on Windows 10 Enterprise 1703 and connected via PuTTY.
When I try to use Docker commands, I get this message:

```
login as: g.koguashvili
g.koguashvili@docker's password:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>docker
panic: Failed to load shell32.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

goroutine 1 [running]:
syscall.(*LazyProc).mustFind(0xc04200acf0)
/usr/local/go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:281 +0x5f
syscall.(*LazyProc).Addr(0xc04200acf0, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:288 +0x32
syscall.CommandLineToArgv(0x1742218, 0xc04202dedc, 0xb, 0xc042004020, 0xc04202df00)
/usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:910 +0x38
os.init.1()
/usr/local/go/src/os/exec_windows.go:102 +0x4c
os.init()
/usr/local/go/src/os/types_windows.go:112 +0x260
fmt.init()
/usr/local/go/src/fmt/scan.go:1210 +0x5c
main.init()
/go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker_windows.go:4 +0x4f
```

How to fix it?